# Libgdx Fill in Color of Image start from the center like an animation

Tags: colors, libgdx

I would like to preform a color fill in from the center of the image in Libgdx. I know I have to use 2 different texture to perform the color change with setColor on the current image to the next image color, but how can I fill in the color starting from the center of the image just like performing an animation?

Comment: what did you try? you could use a mask or draw each pixel per time.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I haven't tried anything yet. Will make some studies regarding to your method. Thanks.